# Angular: How to make a suscribe inside a for loop to wait until its finished

Tags: angular, for-loop, subscribe

good day.

I'm having a problem on how to get this work correctly, the problem is that i have a subscribe function that needs to resolve inside a For Loop like this:

```
     if (item.paquete == 1) {
    
   this.productoService.getInfoPaquetes(item.sku).subscribe(paquetaxo =>{
    this.paquetaxos = paquetaxo;

    for (let index = 0; index < this.paquetaxos.length; index++) {   
      let lineasLocal = {
        salesQuotationNumber: null,
        dataAreaId: "lin",
        itemNumber: this.paquetaxos[index].sku,
        requestedSalesQuantity: Number(this.paquetaxos[index].cantidad),
        shippingWarehouseId: "CHIHCONS",
        fixedPriceCharges: 0,
        salesTaxGroupCode: "VTAS",
        stF_Category: null,
        inventoryLotId: null,
        orderedSalesQuantity: 0,
        salesOrderNumber: null,
        descripcionLinea: null,
        usuario: null,
        salesPrice: Number(this.paquetaxos[index].precio_total),
        ShippingSiteId: "CHIH",
        LineDiscountPercentage: 0
      };
      this.lineas.push(lineasLocal);
    }
   })
  }
```

We have a store, and the code needs to check if the item on the cart its a "promo package" that contains various items, so the loop makes an array of the items it have inside.

The problem here is that for some reason the subscribe dont wait till all the products are finished checking and the array is sent empty to the API that create the orders.

I know that you can have the code that you need to wait inside the promise for it to wait on resolve to work correctly, but this time it cant do that because its inside a for loop.

I have created a workaround where i put the next actions inside a timer fnction so it waits 3 seconds to make the loop finish and get the array filled correctly, but obviusly sometimes it can fail if it takes more than 3 seconds to fill it, depending on how many items the customer have on the cart.

Is there a way to make the suscribe on the for loop waits until its finished to continue with the next chunk of code?

thanks for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using rxjs and forkJoin? Documentation is here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Using your code, it would be something along these lines:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
```

and then

```
if (item.paquete == 1) {
  this.productoService.getInfoPaquetes(item.sku).subscribe(paquetaxo => {
    this.paquetaxos = paquetaxo;

    const observables = this.paquetaxos.map(paquetaxoItem => {
      return this.productoService.getInfoPaquetes(paquetaxoItem.sku);
    });

    forkJoin(observables).subscribe(paquetaxosData => {
      for (let index = 0; index < paquetaxosData.length; index++) {
        let lineasLocal = {
        salesQuotationNumber: null,
        dataAreaId: "lin",
        itemNumber: this.paquetaxos[index].sku,
        requestedSalesQuantity: Number(this.paquetaxos[index].cantidad),
        shippingWarehouseId: "CHIHCONS",
        fixedPriceCharges: 0,
        salesTaxGroupCode: "VTAS",
        stF_Category: null,
        inventoryLotId: null,
        orderedSalesQuantity: 0,
        salesOrderNumber: null,
        descripcionLinea: null,
        usuario: null,
        salesPrice: Number(this.paquetaxos[index].precio_total),
        ShippingSiteId: "CHIH",
        LineDiscountPercentage: 0
      };
        this.lineas.push(lineasLocal);
      }
      
      // Code that depends on this.lineas here.
    });
  });
```

}

Comment: Great answer! OP - For more information and a forkJoin example, here's a video: https://youtu.be/bqIj-m7Uxzk